# How to create a value with an associated type using a normal struct constructor?

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a macro which initializes a struct `T` using `P::Child` from struct `P` where `P: Parent<Child = T>`.

```
macro_rules! init {
    ($t:tt, { $( $k:ident =>  $v:expr ),* }) => {
        <$t as Parent>::Child {
            $( $k: $v ),*
        }
    };
}
```

This macro passes the props as a map which is passed onto the struct's given constructor. Expanded, it would look like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Apple {
    a: i32
}

trait Parent {
    type Child;
}

struct Mango;

impl Parent for Mango {
    type Child = Apple;
}

fn main() {
    let a = <Mango as Parent>::Child {
        a: 4
    };
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Compiling this has the error:

```
error: expected one of `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, or an operator, found `{`
  --> src/main.rs:25:38
   |
25 |     let a = <Mango as Parent>::Child {
   |                                      ^ expected one of `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, or an operator here
```

I have created a macro to initialize a struct in a similar way but I am not able to do it with associated types. I think the compiler does not support it for some reason. Even so, I want to create a macro with such an API.

How could I approach this problem?

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8778c500c60572307559acf00c075d0f&version=undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
macro_rules! init {
    ($t:ty, { $( $k:ident =>  $v:expr ),* }) => {
        {
            type T = <$t as Parent>::Child;
            T {
                $( $k: $v ),*
            }
        }
    };
}
```

My assumption would be that this is a limitation of the parser, not of the compiler's type analysis.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to initialize an associated type.

What you could do is perhaps have the `Child: K` with `K` being a trait having some known constructor (`::new` etc ...), Then call that constructor instead.

Alternatively you can probably initialize a `T` directly instead of `Child`.